# How can i Debug this crystal reports formula?

Tags: sql, debugging, crystal-reports, formula

i have the following on a crystal report form as a formula:

```
IF ({REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT} <> 'Move'
    and {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT} <> 'Daywork'
    and {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT} <> 'Billable Repair'
    and InStr({REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT},'Non-Billable',1) = 0
    and {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT} <> 'Turnkey Daywork') then
    {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.QUANTITY}
else
    0
```

how can i step through it and watch what the current REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT is ?

I really need to see the values of REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT

Comment: Did you try adding it as field to the report details?

Comment: Crystal Reports does NOT have a debugging feature like what you would expect in a proper IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As CR doesn't have a debugging feature, you will need to try one of these approaches:

- Build a formula one piece at a time and view the results on the canvas
- Test complicated logic by returning a value for each case: `If [test] Then 'A' Else If [test] Then 'B' Else 'C'`
- Refactor reusable logic into a custom function

In any case, a better way to structure the logic:

```
IF Not( {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT} IN ['Move','Daywork','Billable Repair','Turnkey Daywork'] )
    AND InStr({REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.ITEMCONCAT},'Non-Billable',1) = 0 THEN
    {REPORT_INVOICE_SUMMARY.QUANTITY}
ELSE
    0
```

Comment: Good to know.  In case of 'link rot', the other thread suggests to create a divide-by-zero error (1/0) at the point where you want to inspect the values of the formula's calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Might be helpful if I post what I did as well.

```
Running Total Formaul (Basic Syntax)
dim debug as number
debug = 0

<buggy code>

formula = debug / debug   <- divide by zero  breakpoint
```

When run in preview you will see the variables with their current values from the formula you are trying to debug.